# webview contents isn't showing when using a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I have a Fragment, ViewPager that has a FragmentPagerAdapter and a
a WebView inside the Fragment. The idea is to use the ViewPager to swipe between fragments that have a webview inside, actually Im using the same fragment but changing the url of the webview in the adapter.
so in the FragmentPagerAdapter I have this code

```
MyFragment frag1 = new MyFragment();
            if(position==0)
            {
                frag1.setUrl("www.google.com");

            }
            else
            {
                frag1.setUrl("www.yahoo.com");
            }
```

and I load the url in the onCreateView in MyFragment

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_vew_fragment,
                container, false);
webview.loadUrl(url);
        return view;
    }
```

The the webView contents is not loaded. so I have a webview saying: web page is not available
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried valid URLs? URLs begin with a scheme (e.g., `http://www.google.com`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid URL **"www.google.com"** so try below :-

```
 frag1.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
```